# Redirect entire site except one directory to a new site - apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to move my current site over to a new domain, except for ONE directory.

Example:

- current site:   oldsite.olddomain.example
- new site:   newdomain.example

So I know I can create an .htaccess redirect entry to do this, and it works, but I want ONE exception - I do NOT want to redirect a specific directory.  I still want this to work:

`http://oldsite.olddmain.example/myspecialdirectory/…` and every file and directory under it.

Can someone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule in the .htaccess file in the document root of *oldsite.olddomain.example*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^myspecialdirectory($|/) http://newdomain.example%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```