# Redirect all pages in direcory except one subdirectory .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to have one URL still being served from a subdirectory on the old domain but redirect all others from the parent directory to the new domain.

www.olddomain.co.uk/directorya/directoryb -> no redirect
www.olddomain.co.uk/directorya -> www.newdomain.co.uk/directorya

This works if the URL is typed with a trailing slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directorya\/directoryb [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/ [L,R=301]
```

So http://www.olddomain.co.uk/directorya/directoryb/ works but http://www.olddomain.co.uk/directorya/directoryb fails.

Tried added $ at the end and other connotations and tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^myspecialdirectory/mynextdirectory($|/) http://newdomain.example%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

from [Redirect entire site except one directory to a new site - apache .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449020/redirect-entire-site-except-one-directory-to-a-new-site-apache-htaccess)

What do I need to do to get  http://www.olddomain.co.uk/directorya/directoryb/ or http://www.olddomain.co.uk/directorya/directoryb to redirect? (while all other http://www.olddomain.co.uk pages go to http://www.newdomain.co.uk

For reasons I don't understand http://www.olddomain.co.uk/directorya/directoryb goes to Google and doesn't redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `THE_REQUEST` variable and make sure this this **very first rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s+/+directorya/directoryb [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/? [L,R=301]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.